# change property disabled in a variable containing html with jquery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable the elements of class "gcf_crud" that are into a variable.

My wrong code is:

```
var defText = ''+
'   <div class="form-group col-md-12">'+
'       <h4 id="minimum-setp">{{title}}</h4>'+
'       <input type="text" class="form-control gcf_crud" id="txtUsuari" value="{{data}}"/>'+
'   </div>';
var defTextDisabled = $(defText).find('.gcf_crud').prop('disabled', true);
```

With this code i'm obtaining only the input but I need all the original html.

How may I do it right?

Regards,
Seak

Comment: _"i'm obtaining only the `<input>`"_. That is because you only select the input: `.find('.gcf_crud')`

Comment: and how to select all but only disable the .gcf_crud class elements?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you want to do, but is this it? https://jsfiddle.net/ku2j3c5m/

Comment: yes! That's exactly what i wanted!! wich differences are between your and mine codes?

Comment: Could you provide a coded example where there is more than one element with the gcf_crud class?

Comment: I added an explanation in a new answer

Comment: Barry Doyle, the blex's answer works fine with many gcf_crud classes: `    var defText = ''+
    ' <div class="form-group col-md-12">'+
    '  <h4 id="minimum-setp">{{title}}</h4>'+
    '  <textarea class="form-control gcf_crud" rows="3" id="txtComentaris">{{data}}</textarea>'+
    '  <input type="text" class="form-control gcf_crud" id="txtUsuari" value="{{data}}"/>'+
    ' </div>';
 var $defTex = $(defText);
 $defText.find('.gcf_crud').prop('disabled', true);
 var defTextDisabled = $defText.html();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `defTextDisabled` variable only returns the input because of `.find('.gcf_crud')`.

But it seems that you need a reference (variable) to a jQuery object containing all the elements. In order to do that, break down your process in steps:

```js
var defText = '<div class="form-group col-md-12">'
            +   '<h4 id="minimum-setp">{{title}}</h4>'
            +   '<input type="text" class="form-control gcf_crud" id="txtUsuari" value="{{data}}"/>'
            + '</div>',
    $defText = $(defText); // Save the entire thing here
    
// Now, you can disable the input
$defText.find('.gcf_crud').prop('disabled', true);

// And use the whole content
$('body').append($defText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I understand perfectly my mistake. Thanks a lot to all. I'm auto-learner and this tricky habbits are difficult to find in tutorials and googleing.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `gcf_crud` class to the main div.

Comment: same behavior. var defTextDisabled is only the input

Comment: Sorry, I've changed my answer.

Comment: Your solution would disable also the div and i wanted only the elements with class gcf_crud

Comment: You're right, my bad I misunderstood the question.  Glad you found an answer.